# Property 'mongoOperations' threw NoSuchMethodException

Tags: mysql, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I am using spring data with mongodb and mysql. The versions I am using are as follows:

```
spring - 3.1.3.RELEASE        
spring-data-jpa - 1.2.0.RELEASE          
spring-data-commons-core - 1.4.0.RELEASE              
spring-data-mongodb - 1.2.1.RELEASE   
mongo-java-driver - 2.7.2   
querydsl - 2.9.0
```

but when I build my project, I get the error below:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSessionRepository': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'mongoOperations' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.setMappingContext(Lorg/springframework/data/mapping/context/MappingContext;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'mongoOperations' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.setMappingContext(Lorg/springframework/data/mapping/context/MappingContext;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    ... 45 more
```

**mongo config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd
">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:local.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.core.*" />


    <!-- mongo settings -->
    <mongo:mongo id="mongo" />

    <mongo:mongo host="${core.mongo.host}" port="${core.mongo.port}"/>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${core.mongo.databasename}" />
    </bean>

    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.project.core.repository.mongo" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate"/>

    <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="com.project.core.util.ApplicationContextProvider"/>


</beans>
```

**main config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd
">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:local.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <import resource="mongo-config.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.core.*" />
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${core.mysql.jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${core.mysql.jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${core.mysql.jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${core.mysql.jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.project.core.domain.mysql"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="projectcore"/>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes">true</prop>
                <prop key="jadira.usertype.databaseZone">jvm</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.project.core.repository.mysql"/>


    <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="com.project.util.ApplicationContextProvider"/>


</beans>
```

Comment: can the one who voted the question down please explain what is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have compatible dependencies - a class in spring-data-mongodb is looking for a method in spring-data-commons that doesn't exist.  This suggests to me that you're not using compatible versions of those two jars.

Looking at the spring data [release notes for this version](http://spring.io/blog/2013/02/13/spring-data-release-train-arora-available) of spring-data-mongodb suggests that for spring-data-mongodb 1.2 you want spring-data-commons 1.5.

I can't find any official documentation on exactly which jars you're going to need, but using Gradle (which manages the dependencies correctly for me) with spring-data-mongodb 1.2. brings in spring-data-commons 1.5.1.  NOTE: this is spring-data-commons not spring-data-commons-**core** (the jar you said you were using).  I can't find any info on which version of core you might need, so I would switch to using spring-data-commons.jar, 1.5.1.

On an unrelated note, mongo-java-driver 2.7.2 is pretty old (actually all the versions you've listed are pretty old).  If possible, look to update to the latest versions of all the jars.

Comment: thanks a lot. the versions that finally worked are :                            spring - 3.1.3.RELEASE,        
spring-data-jpa - 1.3.0.RELEASE,          
spring-data-mongodb - 1.2.0.RELEASE,   
mongo-java-driver - 2.11.0,                                    spring-data-commons  - 1.5.0.RELEASE,
querydsl - 2.9.0